# d3.js changing style of diagonal line

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am brand new to working with with d3.js

I am trying to change the style of the links in the interactive-tree example that comes packaged with d3.js
https://github.com/mbostock/d3/blob/master/examples/tree/tree-interactive.html

they are currently beziers, and I would like them to be angular, i.e. visio class diagram style connections.

seems that there needs to be some extra definition of the diagonal around lines 42-43, but I can't tell from the documentation what that would be.

any help is most appreciated.

Answer (score 4):

You can't do that with `d3.svg.diagonal`. Have a look at [`d3.svg.line`](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line) and in particular the [`interpolate` function](https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/SVG-Shapes#wiki-line_interpolate).